# Xcode: How to have different Bundle Id for "Debug" and "Release"

Tags: xcode, bundle-identifier

I am using Schemes in Xcode.

I cannot specify different Bundle IDs for the "Debug" and "Release" schemes, while I can do for any other scheme that I create. I need to manually edit the Bundle Id in order to install 2 different apps on my iOS (the "Debug" one and the "Release" one).

They seem to be grouped in a common group of properties:

[image]

While this is not the case with the schemes:

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution, I had to put a different Bundle ID for the "Release" and Debug" in Build Settings:

[image]

Comment: In the newer Xcode11, I believe, the setting looks a bit different but I managed to find it using your hint. Thanks

Comment: Great! To clarify the intend, and, hopefully, help it pop up in search, this is useful for separating the restorable state between the debug and release builds: so debugging an application in XCode will not interfere with more routine use of the release build.